# How to fill (join with other table) null values if any from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similar tables, they have the same columns, but different data, both matching different criterions. I want to join Table A to Table B, where some of the values are null.

I tried to look up similar questions but they are not describing my case as far as i can tell.

As an example:
Table A looks like

```
| id | name | age | gender |
  1    Jhon   2      Male
  2    Will   null   null
```

Table B looks like

```
| id | name | age | gender |
  1    Jhon   null   null
  2    Will   3      Male
```

What i would like to make is like

```
| id | name | age | gender |
  1    Jhon   2      Male
  2    Will   3      Male
```

I was trying to left join it, but the result is not as expected. My thought maybe i need to inner join it, then left join maybe, but it is a bit blurry yet.

I'm kinda new to joins, so every thought is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
select id, name,
       coalesce(a.age, b.age) as age,
       coalesce(a.gender, b.gender) as gender
from a join
     b
     using (id, name);
```

The issue is less the type of join then in how you combine the values from the two tables in the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` in the subquery to do `MAX`

```
SELECT id ,name,MAX(age) age ,MAX(gender) gender
FROM (
    SELECT id ,name , age , gender 
    FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id ,name , age , gender 
    TABLE B
) t1
GROUP BY id ,name
```

If your `A` and `B` tables schema are the same I would suggest you use only one table and use a flag to split those two part.

Comment: Thanks, i found both your and @gordon-linoff 's answer useful, however i find his better for my use-case. But thanks anyways. :)